# Linq to sql multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a dictionary `Dictionary<string, List<string>> FilterDictionary` which contains a column name as the key and the value of that key is a list of criteria that is going to be used as a where clause.

I need to query my database and for each column thats in the dictionary query that column with the criteria thats in the list for that key.

Just wondering what the best way to do this was?

This is what I would like to achieve but obviously I know its not as simple as `columnName == filterCriteria`.

```
var originalQuery = from p in productContext.Products
                    select p;
foreach (var item in FilterDictionary)
{
    string columnName = item.Key;

    foreach (var filterCriteria in FilterDictionary)
    {
        originalQuery.Where(columnName == filterCriteria); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there is reason why you aren't using or can't use a collection of `Expression<Func<T, Boolean>>`?

Comment: Simply because ive never done that before. Would you say thats the best route to go down?

Comment: I'd say so.  See my answer.  You get strong typing and compile-time safety this way.  You also get IntelliSense while building your filter conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this instead to hold your collection of filter conditions:

```
var filters = new List<Expression<Func<Product, Boolean>>>();
filters.Add(e => e.Name == "some name");

var originalQuery = from p in productContext.Products
                    select p;
originalQuery = filters
    .Aggregate(originalQuery, (current, condition) => current.Where(condition));
```

At the end of the `foreach` loop, `originalQuery` will have logically `AND`ed together all of the criteria held in `filters`.

Comment: Watch the modified closure gotcha! (capture `filter` in an in-loop variable)

Comment: @GertArnold Right - you can use a LINQ aggregate instead to avoid that and make the code more readable, which I've edited in.

Comment: True, that's the way to go, stay within the concept!